# found a link of a chat app using angular from git which i downloaded and tried open in vscode but it is unable to open it is sowing this error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, git, node-modules

D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\e2e>ng s -o
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active(node:5292) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
10% building 3/4 modules 1 active ...s\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:71
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:47:13)
at processResource (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
at runLoaders (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
at NormalModule.build (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
at Compilation.buildModule (D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
at D:\mearn stack\Angular\whatsapp-clone\Whatsapp-Clone-in-Angular-0865222531df2c8ee55a7db46033f0e2972d3d6c\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.0

this is the error that i encountered while i tried to  ng serve open the file

i tried ng seve --open in the terminal which this error is showing

Answer (score 0):

- Most of the times this error means that you have incompatible version of nodejs.
- May be you should try downgrading the nodejs, may be  using `nvm`.
- Please check out compatible nodejs version for the angular version (check from package.json or `ng --version` or `ng version` command) you are using .